# Simplifying a expression which involves a square root: $\sqrt{36 - 4x^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, factoring

I know that $ 2 \sqrt{9-x^2}$ is the alternate form for $\sqrt{36 - 4x^2}$. I tried but i didn't figure out how to get there. Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a consequence of the fact that $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$.
Note that in your case, we have the following:
$$\sqrt{36-4x^2}=\sqrt{4(9-x^2)}$$
Applying what I wrote earlier, we are left with the following.
$$\sqrt{4}\sqrt{9-x^2}$$
This of course simplifies to $2\sqrt{9-x^2}$.